# I get an error when trying to find my pico in thonny

Tags: pi-pico

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/thonny/workbench.py", line 865, in _post_backend_menu
    if uf2_device_is_present_in_bootloader_mode():
  File "/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/thonny/plugins/micropython/uf2dialog.py", line 602, in uf2_device_is_present_in_bootloader_mode
    for vol in list_volumes(skip_letters=["A"]):
  File "/app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/thonny/misc_utils.py", line 101, in list_volumes
    mount_output = subprocess.check_output("mount").splitlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mount'
```

Can someone tell me what it means?

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using Windows Thonny?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please put more details on what you are trying to do, and what you are using, etc.

Comment: This is on my raspberry pi 4b running pop os, and I'm trying to use thorny to edit and upload code to an attached pico, but when I click the button at the bottom right of the window that usually let's you save the code to the pico I get this error message instead